# Committing the changes in Handsontable from outside

Tags: handsontable

By Default when we enter a value inside a cell in Handsontable and the press Enter key or go to another cell or other part of the page, the value we have already entered into the cell will be committed automatically (after validation).

But I have a new requirement now. I want to manually commit the changes form outside of Handsontable (e.g. with calling a JavaScript function).

The real story is that I have rendered dropdown control inside some cells in Handsontable. When the user enters a number in a cell without pressing Enter key; and then clicks on the dropdown control in another cell; I do not have access to their new entered value.

I am going to commit their former changes when they click on the dropdown.

Any Idea?

**Update:**

I created  a jsFiddle and did my best to keep it as simple as possible. http://jsfiddle.net/mortezasoft/3c2mN/3/

If you change the Maserati word to something else and without pressing Enter choose an option in dropdown, you can still see the name Maserati is shown as an alert dialog.

```
   <div id="example"></div>

   var data = [
      ["", "Maserati"],
      ["", ""],

    ];

    $('#example').handsontable({
        data: data,
        minSpareRows: 1,
        colHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true,
        cells: function (row, col, prop) {

            var cellProperties = {};

            if (col===0 && row===0) {
                cellProperties.renderer = selectBoxRenderer;
                cellProperties.readOnly =true;
            }

            return cellProperties;
        }
    });
    function selectBoxRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        var $select = $("<select><option></option> <option>Show the name</option></select>");
        var $td = $(td);
        $select.on('mousedown', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation(); //prevent selection quirk
        });

        $td.empty().append($select);
        $select.change(function () {
            //Default value is Maserati but we are gonna change it.
            alert($('#example').handsontable('getData')[0][1]);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `instance.destroyEditor()` to the `mousedown` handler on `$select`. This will commit the changes on first click, but will also require another click to open the select menu.

```
$select.on('mousedown', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); //prevent selection quirk
  instance.destroyEditor();
});
```

The reason behind second click problem is that `instance.destroyEditor()` re-renders the table, which causes the original `select` element to be destroyed, so the click event cannot take effect.

To solve this, add

```
if ($td.find('select').length!=0) return;
```

at the beginning of the renderer. This way existing `select` elements will not be overwritten when re-rendering.

Comment: Unfortunately Requiring a second click makes this trick useless.

Comment: Thanks for your trick but I had already tried this one as well. I have vertical scroll-bar in my sheet. If user scroll the sheet and we do not render the `select` constantly, there will be a mess in the sheet and `select` elements overlap each other. 
Even though I did an ugly trick to support this functionality but it seems this feature has to be fixed in the core library according to our discussion here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/handsontable/vECWZzf0ZXA

Comment: You can introduce a flag, which holds the information, whether ``render`` was called due to the event on ``select`` element and only in that case skip rendering.

Comment: I used this trick except with the 'change' event instead of 'mousedown' and it works great to commit the change after the dropdown selection is made